# How To Autoplay Embedded Videos in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Can anyone help me on how to make my embedded video in Ionic framework to autoplay when it loads.

example: I have a videos button then when I click it, it will go directly to the video then autoplay it

thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5_audio_en_video_gebruiken

Comment: .mov file support ionic or android?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use replace "&" with "?" in the url the video will autoload.

So your url would be: http://www.youtube.com/embed/qPMIQobB3ZM?autoplay=1

Seems like Google should have made this available, but I would say using a "?" makes more sense than using the "&".

Answer (score 0):

In iOS HTML a video only starts on user input. You can't control this behaviour in ios Safari. Because you mention 'Ionic Framework' I assume you're building a app with Cordova / PhoneGape / Ionic builder? You could set `<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>` to the config.xml file http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html

Embed the player with:

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>

<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      autoplay : 1
    });
  }
</script>
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters